# How do I make a formula with Mulitple IF statements in seperate cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I want to make a formula that sums IF C36:C160 = "Text" and if E36:H160 = "Some other text"/2

Hope this makes sense!

```
  -SUM.IF(E36:H160;"*LAURAS*";A36:A160)/2
```

basicly this with the added C36:C160="Mad"

Tried this SUMIFS:

```
  SUM.IFS(A36:A160;C36:C160;"Mad";E36:H160;"LAURAS")
```

But comes up with an error message.

Comment: SUMIFS maybe???

Comment: The ranges must be the same size and shape with SUMIFS().  The question is whether the value can be anywhere in columns E through H or does it need to be in all those columns for the row to summed?

Comment: i Have tried the sumifs formula (Probably doing it wrong) like this   -SUM.IFS(A36:A160;C36:C160;"Mad";E36:H160;"LAURAS")  And when i do this it comes with a error message.

Comment: I am writing some other stuff in the E36:H160 aswell, so the value can be anywhere in them.

Comment: Can the text value be found in more than one cell in the same row or only once per row?

Comment: C36:C160 this part is like a drawdown menu with other text examples. But in this formula it will always be "Mad" . E36:H160 this part wil be "LAURAS" + text description. and A36:A160 will be the sum area. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I have added a picture in the top of the post. Maybe it makes it abit clearer what i wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since E:G are merged the value in only in E.  So a simple SUMIFS will work:

```
=SUMIFS(A36:A160;C36:C160;"Mad";E36:E160;"*LAURAS*")
```

Comment: Oh lord, i have used so much time getting around this. And i should have just basicly changed 1 letter? Amazing thank you Scott! :D